# How to find exact location of error in this log file?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, apple-developer

I found many similar solutions regarding how to fix these types of crashes by finding the exact location of the error but im all confused in my log file. In those solutions I saw it was clearly mentioned in which files the error was. But I don't seem to understand mine. Can anyone tell me how to read this?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000018569e1a8
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [2868]

Triggered by Thread:  0


Kernel Triage:
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018569e1a8 closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 300 (AssertCommon.swift:96)
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018569df48 closure #1 in closure #1 in _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 220 (AssertCommon.swift:89)
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000018569d83c _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 232 (AssertCommon.swift:85)
3   TestAlertApp                    0x0000000102992da4 0x102834000 + 1437092
4   TestAlertApp                    0x0000000102992320 0x102834000 + 1434400
5   TestAlertApp                    0x000000010288c8a0 0x102834000 + 362656
6   AudioToolbox                    0x000000018b839d1c AudioSessionRequestRecordPermission + 76 (AudioSession.cpp:0)
7   AudioSession                    0x000000018a0640a8 softLink_AudioSessionRequestRecordPermission + 52 (SoftLinking_AudioToolbox_iOS.mm:48)
8   AudioSession                    0x000000018a05af74 -[AVAudioSession requestRecordPermission:] + 116 (AVAudioSession_iOS.mm:1328)
9   TestAlertApp                    0x0000000102991f50 0x102834000 + 1433424
10  TestAlertApp                    0x000000010299187c 0x102834000 + 1431676
11  TestAlertApp                    0x0000000102994f70 0x102834000 + 1445744
12  TestAlertApp                    0x000000010288c37c 0x102834000 + 361340
13  TestAlertApp                    0x0000000102b03b98 closure #1 in AlertMeViewController.initiateAlertMe(_:_:) + 1836 (AlertMeViewController.swift:311)
14  TestAlertApp                    0x00000001029e724c 0x102834000 + 1782348
15  TestAlertApp                    0x0000000102cfbb64 closure #1 in static SLWebRequest.post(url:params:headers:completionHandler:) + 640 (SLWebRequest.swift:55)
16  Alamofire                       0x000000010352bcb0 partial apply for specialized closure #2 in closure #2 in closure #3 in closure #1 in DownloadRequest.response<A>(queue:responseSerializer:completionHandler:) + 48
17  Alamofire                       0x00000001034c441c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018091d924 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018091f670 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018092db70 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 944 (inline_internal.h:2601)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180c65d84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1795)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180c1ff5c __CFRunLoopRun + 2540 (CFRunLoop.c:3144)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180c33468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
24  GraphicsServices                0x000000019c7d738c GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001835d65d0 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3493)
26  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183354f74 UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5047)
27  TestAlertApp                    0x000000010289654c 0x102834000 + 402764
28  dyld                            0x00000001032adaa4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)
```

Comment: Look at line 311 of AlertMeViewController.swift. It appears to be a closure handling a network response

Comment: @Paulw11 ok thanks. so I can ignore everything else ?

Comment: Well, not ignore as such, but that is the last point in *your code* that was executed

Comment: The error has signs of a memory related bug (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/identifying-the-cause-of-common-crashes#Determine-Whether-the-Crash-Is-a-Swift-Runtime-Error). If so, the problem might be elsewhere and the crash location just indicates where it was eventually detected. Have you tried Xcode's address sanitizer?

Comment: @Codo no I haven't tried that. I will try that now. Thanks to both of you for at least telling me where to start